# Looking to see how I can split a string into two parts, while keeping full words intact

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As the title says, looking to see how I can split a string into two parts, while keeping full words intact, and having access to both parts with JavaScript. I am using this string in a pug file.

For instance, I have a very long string

```
let str = `hello i am a very long string that needs to be split into two different parts! thank you so much for helping.'
```

I want the first 70 characters, to use as a headline, then the rest to use for the body of the element.

I have used this regex that I found on an older post that gives me the first 70+ characters, with full words...

```
str.replace(/^([\s\S]{70}[^\s]*)[\s\S]*/, "$1")
```

which does what I want it to do. But now I need to figure out if there is a way to get the rest of that string?

```
str1 = `hello i am a very long string that needs to be split into two different`
str2 = `parts! thank you so much for helping.`
```

Again, using this in a pug file, so if there is a simple answer, I would love that. Otherwise I suppose I could just write a function and import the script to the pug view.

[react code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtN9g.png)